# AJAX in ASP.NET web pages 2

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-webpages

I need to build fast some simple web applications with simple CRUD operations using ASP.NET

My straight choice would be to go with standard ASP Web Pages 2 and i will.

Most of them will be 1-2 pages long.

I need to find an approach to make it more user friendly and AJAXify them.

In my mind in order to that would be to implicate JQuery. But i suppose that this takes me to Web API in order to get/set data in JSon...

And if this is the only way to go , how i sould go about it? can web pages support Web APi or i have to go to MVC?

For example i would like to update tables in my page by pressing buttons or selecting UI elements (drop down boxes)..

**Update:** I followed [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms) and i changed only the imports in global.asax as follows:

```
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Http" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Http.Handlers" %>
```

and it seems that it works now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the ASP.NET Web API ([with web forms](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms)) and [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/)

Why?

The Web API makes serving JSON very easy and encourages a RESTful approach without constraining yorr options (as RPC style calls still have their place IMO).

Knockout has good documentation, tutorials and great support. I've built a couple of really 'ajaxy' apps with the Web API, Bootstrap and Knockout and can recommend you take a look.

Comment: I agree with you as iam just reading this..BUT as strange as it sounds because i am a winforms developer, i DONT want to go to WebForms.. Can i use it in Web pages 2?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I would guess that you can use the Web API with Web Pages 2 - it /probably/ all sits on top of the main ASP.NET dll's